# iOS 5 iPhone breakout style app design

Tags: ios, design-patterns

I am attempting to make a breakout style game in iOS 5 and have a few questions about design. (This is just a learning exercise)

I plan to have 2 main controllers:

- BlockBreakerViewController - Sets the initial settings such as power-ups and difficulty
- GameViewController - Manages the game state and its subviews (Ball, paddle, blocks)

UiViews

- PaddleView (one)
- BallView (one)
- BlockView (many)

Models

- GamePlay - Manages the entire game state including the ball, paddle, blocks, and score

My questions are...

1. should I break up the model into separate objects?
2. What should the relationship between the UiViews and models?

EDIT: Now that I have the general questions answered, how can I apply this to the "Ball" object.

Right now I have a BallView that implements drawRect. I want to create a Ball model. Do I need a Ball model, BallView, and BallViewController? This seems like overkill. Should the GameViewController talk to the BallViewController?

Comment: It is common to have the model and view integrated on the same object for games, e.g Cocos2D sprites. Perhaps you can have a Stage object containing all the blocks. If I remember correctly, some blocks give you multiple balls at once...

Comment: I think each game object should definitely be a separate object. OO and game logic mix well.

Comment: Just have a ball view that doubles as ball model (view object already has position information, to give an example). Game objects like your ball don't need to be controllers, in my opinion. Have 1 object manage the game logic. Don't push MVC too far; it is a game not a web application.

Comment: I use my own OpenGL-based graphic lib (similar to Cocos2D, but more suited to my needs), yet the idea is the same even if you use UIKit. Have an Update method called every frame and manage your game logic from there (including all interactions between game objects, and user input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my answers to your questions based on the way I like to structure games in a model-view-controller style:

**(1)** Yes, I would recommend that you build your model in a very object oriented manner, because this is the most logic part of the game, and the heart of your game. It is the easiest part to structure, while at the same time its structure makes a big impact on the process of building your game. A good way to think when you are structuring a model and what parts it should include is to think like this:

"If I were to make this same game on two completely different platforms, lets say iPhone and and Xbox, and they should be able to play agaist each other - what code would the two games have in common?"

The part of the code that would be exactly the same is the **model**.

In this case I would say its something like: GameBoard (or other suitable name for the area where the ball is bouncing around), Paddle, Ball, Block etc. Also things like Level, ScoreKeeper, GameHandler (master class to keep track of the rules of the game), Player (class to represent a physical player) etc etc could be suitable classes.

The model keeps track of everything that concern the rules of the game, like the balls and paddle´s position, velocity and so on on the game field.

**(2)** Your UI-classes have another task - to transfer your game objects to the iPhone so that the user can see, move and hear them.

There are lots of ways to structure this. Typically you don't need to have a UIView subclass or a CCSprite (Cocos2D) subclass for each type of object you have. After all, mostly they are just one thing, a sprite. However there must be logics to transfer the objects position in the game world to the sprites on the screen. (even if a 1:1 relation would be recommended here for simplicity)

Each game object could reference a sprite for example, or you could have a GameScene class that holds all the sprites etc etc. I recommend to try to split things up to have some structure, like having one class that draws the game board and the game objects, another one to draw the HUD, a third one to draw a pretty background with some movement in it etc, however this require you to have some kind of layer structure.

The last important thing is that you have a controller with an update method that is run through by the game engine on regular time intervals, and that this update method first triggers the model to update and then the UI to draw, as well as the user to interact. This is the controller that binds everything together.

I would recommend you to try out Cocos2d as well. It helps you to grasp many of the concepts in game programming. You will find what things Cocoa Touch do better and what things Cocos2d do better pretty fast.